Unclear solution or error? (Boyd, convex analysis)
Exercise $3.32a$ of Boyd - Convex Optimisation.
Prove that if $f, g$ are both increasing (or decreasing) functions and they are positive, and both convex, then $fg$ is convex.
The solution manual (freely available on github) reports this solution, which I don't get.
$$f(\theta x + (1-\theta)y)g(\theta x + (1-\theta)y) \leq (\theta f(x) + (1-\theta)f(y))(\theta g(x) + (1-\theta)g(y))$$
The right hand terms is then said to be
$$\leq \theta f(x)g(x) + (1-\theta)f(y)g(y) + \theta(1-\theta)[f(y) - f(x)][g(x) - g(y)]$$
Now I had the intuition that he, for the first two terms, just used an upper bound that is
$$\theta^2f(x)g(x) \leq \theta f(x)g(x)$$
since $\theta^2 \leq \theta$ as $\theta \in [0, 1]$, and the same for the other squared term.
Where on Earth does the third term arise from? I tried to expand it but there are no smart cancellations. And he says that since they are both increasing, the third term is less or equal than zero, hence another upper bound, where it remains
$$f(\theta x + (1-\theta)y)g(\theta x + (1-\theta)y) \leq \theta f(x)g(x) + (1-\theta)f(y)g(y)$$
Whence the thesis.
I don't get that passage

\begin{eqnarray}
(t f(x)&&+ (1-t)f(y)) (t g(x) + (1-t)g(y)) \\
&=& t^2 f(x)g(x)+t(1-t)[f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)]+(1-t)^2f(y)g(y) \\
&=& t^2 f(x)g(x)+t(1-t)(f(y)-f(x))(g(x)-g(y))+(1-t)^2f(y)g(y) + t(1-t)(f(x)g(x)+f(y)g(y))\\
&\le& t^2 f(x)g(x)+(1-t)^2f(y)g(y) + t(1-t)(f(x)g(x)+f(y)g(y))\\
&=& t f(x)g(x)+(1-t)f(y)g(y)
\end{eqnarray}
The only part than needs explanation is why $t(1-t)(f(y)-f(x))(g(x)-g(y)) \le 0$. Since $f,g$ are both increasing (or decreasing) and we have either $x\le y$ or $y \le x$, the result follows.

The final result was actually clear. It was the algebraic manipulation that was obscure... Thank you again!
